# Adding text outlines to the Section command

Tags: sectioning, text-decorations

I am learning LaTeX and I want to add a outline to the text of the section title and was wondering if there is a nice way to adjust the command to include the outline in the section command rather than having to specify it every time I create a new section.

Currently, I am using the contour package as such (I am using LuaLaTeX and `fontpsec` for custom font as well) with a setup like this

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\secfont{TitleFont}
\definecolor{seccolor}{HTML}{58170D}
\definecolor{secoutline}{HTML}{D2D4BC}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{.4pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\color{secoutline}\fontsize{24}{28}\secfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}

....
\section*{\contour{seccolor}{Section Title}}
```

And while this looks the way I want it to, is there away to include the `\countour` command in `\titleformat` so that I don't have to include it in the section everytime

Since the text from `\contour` in placed in `{}` I am unsure as to how I can add this to `\titleformat`

Current Test code

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{sectioncolor}{HTML}{58170D}
\definecolor{sectionoutline}{HTML}{D0D2C7}

\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{.6pt}

\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{24}{28}\selectfont\color{sectioncolor}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{\contour{sectionoutline}{Testing Section}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, fragments of code are not very useful: post a complete small document we can copy-paste-compile to work on. Nobody wants to begin by guessing what should be in your preamble and figuring out what's needed to reproduce your situation. You ***know***. Help us to help you by telling us.

Comment: Use the explicit option for **titlesec** and then include `\contour{...}{#1}` in `\titleformat`. Probably. I'd test it if you'd provided an example.

Comment: I added some test code without all the special fonts

Comment: I already used your earlier code and substituted a font I have for the one I don't have. So my example below is based on your earlier code, but, hopefully, it will still do the job.

Comment: It does, I had made a quick edit to remove that specific font but everything works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. It is better to avoid fonts people might not have. (My answer is guilty on this score, too, as I chose a random system font.) I just figured I could adapt that bit and went ahead. Glad it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `explicit` option for **titlesec** then you can use `#1` for the section title in the definition. I've minimised your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\secfont{Quintessential-Regular}

\definecolor{sectioncolor}{HTML}{58170D}
\definecolor{sectionoutline}{HTML}{D0D2C7}

\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{.6pt}

\usepackage[noindentafter,explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\color{sectioncolor}\fontsize{24}{28}\secfont}{\thesection}{1em}{\contour{sectionoutline}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Testing Section}
\end{document}
```

[image: quintessential testing]